# How can I delete a user which is logged in and have a uid=0

Tags: linux

I want to delete a user which have zero user-id but I found error : userdel: user hgw_admin is currently logged in.

Comment: You must make him/her leave the system first. You can do it politely or also killing his/her session.

Comment: You do **not** want to delete that account.  Also this is off topic here.

Comment: I can not expect that user politely leaves her session actually this is my challenge.. I killed the session but still got the same result. please help @fedorqui

Comment: Note that this is off-topic. User must have some files opened, you can check with `lsof`. Also, note that user id = 0 is also for `root`, so it can be dangerous to delete the user.

Comment: yes you are right. I can understand the risk, but still this is the requirement for customer perspective. I checked this with lsof but none file is of the specific user. one interesting thing is that I can not able to delete the user anymore. It can only be possible if I again ssh and exit and then delete the user. Please help @fedorqui

Comment: snap Shot of my script.
user_list.txt contains all the user.
for user in $(< user_list.txt)
do
pids=`ps -eaf | grep -e "ssh" -e "su" -e "sshd" | grep -w "$user" | awk '{print $2}'` >/dev/null 2>&1
if [[ -z $pids ]]
then
#\userdel -r $user
echo "no process associated with the user $user"
else
\kill -9 $pids >/dev/null 2>&1
\echo "process ($pids) killed with user $user "
\sleep 2
\userdel -r $user
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
echo "user deletion is not successful"
\userdel -r $user
fi
fi
done

please help

Comment: Adding one more interesting thing, if I create a user with different uid(except than 0), still I can not able to delete a user.
please look into it.
1) Entry in /etc/password
   user2:x:502:502::/var/hnbgw/user2:/bin/bash
2) userdel user2
userdel: user user2 is currently logged in

3) lsof -u user2
 [ get nothing ]
I am using centos. (CentOS release 5.6 (Final)

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue. Actually a bash associated with ssh must also be killed before killing the ssh connection.